# Verify the limit is wrong

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis, solution-verification, proof-explanation

I want to verify that this limit is wrong, but I still have difficulties in the final part.

$$\lim_{x\to 2} \dfrac{1}{x-3} = +\infty.$$

By the definition: $\forall M>0,\ \exists \delta_M > 0$ such that when $|x - x_0| < \delta_M$ we have $f(x) > M$.

In this case the characteristic inequality reads

$$\frac{1}{x-3} > M \implies x < \frac{1+3M}{M}.$$

In this scenario I could write

$$x - 2 < \frac{1+M}{M} - 2,$$

which means we could take $\delta_M = \frac{1+M}{M} - 2.$

Now though I got stuck because it seems like that $\forall M > 0$ there exists a $\delta$, but I cannot tell why the limit is false, except if I think about $M$ as a very large number. In this case I would get a right neighbourhood of $3$, which is what I need for the limit to be true (and not $x\to 2$).

Is there a way in which I can reason when dealing with exercises like this? (Both in the case of true and false limits to be verified). Thank you!

Comment: For $M > 1$ your proposed $\delta$ is negative.

Comment: For $\lvert x-2\rvert<\frac12$, $-2\le\frac1{x-3}\lt0$, so we can't have $\frac1{x-3}>M$ for, say, $M>3$

Comment: A more general remark; When you are trying to prove that something does not fit a certain definition, it will generally provide insight to first negate the definition, since what you are trying to show is precisely that the negation is true, in your case, what you really want to show is that there is some $M$ such that no matter how small you take $\delta$ to be, the implication $$0<|x-2|<\delta \implies |f(x)|>M$$ is false, i.e. you want to show that for sufficiently small neighbourhoods of $2$, $f$ is a bounded function

Comment: And to do this, it is actually sufficient to exhibit a *single* neighbourhood of $2$ on which $f$ is bounded, since any smaller neighbourhood would be contained in that neighbourhood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your solution, as pointed out in a comment by [Tzimmo](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/239702/tzimmo),

is that for $M>1$ your proposed $\delta_M$ is negative.

In fact, you won't be able to find positive $\delta_M$, for $M>0$,

such that $\dfrac1{x-3}>M$ when $\lvert x-2\rvert<\delta_M$,

because for $\lvert x-2\rvert\le\frac12$, $\;-2\le\dfrac1{x-3}\lt0$.

Comment: In fact, $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 2} \dfrac{1}{x-3}=\dfrac1{2-3}=-1.\,$